# How can I find start and end points from a road layer?

Tags: postgis

I have a shapefile with geometries MultiLineString and Point. I have loaded the shapefile into PostGIS. From that table I cannot find any (lon,lat) except geometrical values with some SRID,.... columns.

How about knowing of nodes, edges, start point and end point for a particular layer that has above geometries; and to create a start point and end point from a shape file

I have tried few shapefiles, finally stopped with

```
Error:Start vertex was not found.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for a linesttring you can use these funcs. more info [here](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_EndPoint.html).

> ST_EndPoint — Returns the last point of a LINESTRING geometry as a
>   POINT.
>
> ST_StartPoint — Returns the first point of a LINESTRING geometry as a
>   POINT.
>
> ST_DumpPoints — Returns a set of geometry_dump (geom,path) rows of all
>   points that make up a geometry.

**Example:**

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_EndPoint('LINESTRING(1 1 2, 1 2 3, 0 0 5)'));
  st_asewkt
--------------
 POINT(0 0 5)
(1 row)
```

i hope it helps you....

Comment: Is there any possibility that could extract vertices for a geometry_dump(geom,path) row for a point/lineString ex: "({1},0101000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001440)"